The aptos-debugger tool outputs the error "VersionData at {version} is missing" when attempting to restore
After running a local testnet with the aptos CLI on my local machine, I used the aptos-debugger tool to continuously perform backup to the local filesystem. When I attempted to restore the backup data with the aptos-debugger tool, an error occurred while restoring the state snapshot database: VersionData at {version} is missing.
To reproduce,

Build aptos-debugger from aptos-core repository. (tag: v1.12.2)
Run a local testnet with aptos node run-local-testnet --test-dir ./.aptos/testnet command.
Run a backup tool with aptos-debugger aptos-db backup continuously --metadata-cache-dir ./.aptos/backup/mc --local-fs-dir ./.aptos/backup/db --transaction-batch-size 10 command.
Then, try to restore the backup data with aptos-debugger aptos-db restore bootstrap-db --local-fs-dir ./.aptos/backup/db --target-db-dir .aptos/backup/restored --ledger-history-start-version 0 command.
An error occurs: buffered state creation failed.: Other("VersionData at 129037 is missing.").

Full error messages:
...
2024-05-31T08:01:32.207850Z [tokio-runtime-worker] INFO storage/backup/backup-cli/src/backup_types/transaction/restore.rs:561 KV replayed. {"accumulative_tps":4468,"version":109999}
2024-05-31T08:01:34.156565Z [tokio-runtime-worker] INFO storage/aptosdb/src/state_store/mod.rs:198 self.skip_usage=false
2024-05-31T08:01:34.335957Z [tokio-runtime-worker] INFO storage/backup/backup-cli/src/backup_types/transaction/restore.rs:561 KV replayed. {"accumulative_tps":4486,"version":119999}
2024-05-31T08:01:35.811889Z [tokio-runtime-worker] INFO storage/aptosdb/src/state_store/mod.rs:198 self.skip_usage=false
2024-05-31T08:01:35.958763Z [tokio-runtime-worker] INFO storage/backup/backup-cli/src/backup_types/transaction/restore.rs:561 KV replayed. {"accumulative_tps":4548,"version":129037}
2024-05-31T08:01:35.958860Z [main] INFO storage/backup/backup-cli/src/backup_types/transaction/restore.rs:573 KV Replay finished. {"accumulative_tps":4548,"total_replayed":129037}
2024-05-31T08:01:35.959224Z [main] INFO storage/backup/backup-cli/src/backup_types/transaction/restore.rs:265 transaction restore succeeded.
2024-05-31T08:01:35.959233Z [main] INFO storage/backup/backup-cli/src/coordinators/restore.rs:307 Starting restore DB from version 129037 to target version 129100
2024-05-31T08:01:35.959238Z [main] INFO storage/backup/backup-cli/src/coordinators/restore.rs:319 Start restoring tree snapshot at 129037 with db_next_version 129037
2024-05-31T08:01:35.959249Z [main] INFO storage/backup/backup-cli/src/backup_types/state_snapshot/restore.rs:99 state snapshot restore started. Manifest: state_epoch_269_ver_129037.46f0/state.manifest
2024-05-31T08:01:47.449812Z [main] INFO storage/backup/backup-cli/src/backup_types/state_snapshot/restore.rs:224 State chunk added. {"chunk":0,"chunks_to_add":1,"last_idx":100459,"values_per_second":13047}
2024-05-31T08:01:48.424160Z [main] INFO storage/aptosdb/src/state_store/mod.rs:448 Initializing BufferedState. {"latest_snapshot_version":129037,"num_transactions":129038}
thread 'main' panicked at storage/aptosdb/src/state_store/mod.rs:578:10:
buffered state creation failed.: Other("VersionData at 129037 is missing.") 
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
2024-05-31T08:01:48.427766Z [state-committer] INFO storage/schemadb/src/lib.rs:357 Dropped RocksDB. {"rocksdb_name":"state_merkle_db"}
2024-05-31T08:01:48.431262Z [main] INFO storage/schemadb/src/lib.rs:357 Dropped RocksDB. {"rocksdb_name":"ledger_db"}

System Information:

Aptos Core Version: v1.12.2
Rust Version: 1.75.0
Computer OS: macOS 14.5

It appears that the restored ledger_db lacks usage information. At the code where the error VersionData at {version} is missing. is printed, I tried inserting all values for {version} starting from 0, but each one resulted in the same error.
Also, this error occurred only when I tried to restore with --ledger-history-start-version 0 option. According to the comment on the code, aptos-debugger tool seems to restore StateStorageUsage only for transactions whose version is less than the value of ledger-history-start-version. I don't know why this constraint in the code, but anyway there is.
